# Linux ksu (kerberized super user) command fails to use cached service (host) tickets

Tags: linux, active-directory, kerberos, sudo, kinit

Questions at the end

**About my environment**

I have tried in two different environments: (i) Linux Ubuntu 16.04LTS server enrolled in Active Directory (Microsoft) Domain and (ii) Linux Ubuntu 16.04LTS server enrolled in a FreeIPA Realm.

Krb5 binary version:

```
$ strings libkrb5.so | grep BRAND
KRB5_BRAND: krb5-1.13.2-final 1.13.2 2015050
```

**What I like to do**

I'm trying to use [*ksu*](http://web.mit.edu/Kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/user/user_commands/ksu.html) command to login on the current host (*authdemo4.addemo.it*) as another user: *kservice*.
In detail I'm trying (i) to obtain a service ticket for user *kservice* for the host *authdemo4.addemo.it*, (ii) to save the ticket in a MIT cache file */media/public/krb_kservice* and (iii) to provide this ticket to *ksu* command in order to login as *kservice*.

**it should be possibile**

The *ksu* MIT documentation states that using a service ticket from cache file is possible, let's quote:

> Otherwise, ksu looks for an appropriate Kerberos ticket in the source
>   cache. The ticket can either be for the end-server or a ticket
>   granting ticket (TGT) for the target principal’s realm. If the ticket
>   for the end-server is already in the cache, it’s decrypted and
>   verified. If it’s not in the cache but the TGT is, the TGT is used to
>   obtain the ticket for the end-server. The end-server ticket is then
>   verified.

**My experiments and results**

When using the TGT Kerberos ticket.. it works like a charm:

```
$ kinit -c /media/public/krb_kservice  kservice
Password for kservice@ADDEMO.IT:
$ ksu kservice -n kservice@ADDEMO.IT -c FILE:/media/public/krb_kservice
Authenticated kservice@ADDEMO.IT
Account kservice: authorization for kservice@ADDEMO.IT successful
Changing uid to kservice (50006)
groups: cannot find name for group ID 50024
kservice@authdemo4:/home/userlab$
```

This is the cache content, there is only the TGT:

```
$ klist -c /media/public/krb_kservice
Ticket cache: FILE:/media/public/krb_kservice
Default principal: kservice@ADDEMO.IT

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
11/08/2017 11:44:07  11/08/2017 21:44:07  krbtgt/ADDEMO.IT@ADDEMO.IT
        renew until 11/09/2017 11:44:03
```

When trying with the end-server Kerberos ticket (service ticket) it fails, *ksu* ignores the cached ticket and asks for the user password:

```
$ kinit   -S HOST/authdemo4@ADDEMO.IT  -c /media/public/krb_kservice  kservice
Password for kservice@ADDEMO.IT:
$ ksu kservice -n kservice@ADDEMO.IT -c FILE:/media/public/krb_kservice
WARNING: Your password may be exposed if you enter it here and are logged in remotely using an unsecure (non-encrypted) channel.
Kerberos password for kservice@ADDEMO.IT: :
```

Please note that I have tried all these service principals: *host/authdemo4.addemo.it@ADDEMO.IT*, *HOST/authdemo4.addemo.it@ADDEMO.IT*, *host/authdemo4@ADDEMO.IT*, *HOST/authdemo4@ADDEMO.IT*

This is the cache content, there is only the service ticket:

```
$ klist -f -c /media/public/krb_kservice
Ticket cache: FILE:/media/public/krb_kservice
Default principal: kservice@ADDEMO.IT

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
11/08/2017 13:51:05  11/08/2017 23:51:05  HOST/authdemo4@ADDEMO.IT
        renew until 11/09/2017 13:51:02, Flags: FPRIA
```

It is proxiable-forwardable-renewable-initial-preauthenticated ticket.

In brief: **my attempt with end-server service ticket doesn't work**.

I checked with Wireshark the *ksu* Kerberos requests to the DC in order to find differences with my requested service ticket. Service name is the same "*host/authdemo4*", *ksu* adds the *canonizable* flag to the ticket and it asks the ticket to the TGS while *kinit* sends the request to the AS :-(

**Update, using kvno command (fails)**

I examined deeply with Wireshark the TGS request/response performed by *ksu* and I found out that the correct service is: *host/authdemo4@ADDEMO.IT*

I have tried with *kvno* to insert the service ticket into the cache:

Insert TGT:

```
$ kinit kservice -c ./prova.cc
Password for kservice@ADDEMO.IT:
```

Insert service ticket:

```
$ kvno host/authdemo4@ADDEMO.IT -c ./prova.cc
host/authdemo4@ADDEMO.IT: kvno = 17
```

Check cache content:

```
$ klist -c ./prova.cc
Ticket cache: FILE:./prova.cc
Default principal: kservice@ADDEMO.IT

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
11/09/2017 15:18:53  11/10/2017 01:18:53  krbtgt/ADDEMO.IT@ADDEMO.IT
        renew until 11/10/2017 15:18:48
11/09/2017 15:19:07  11/10/2017 01:18:53  host/authdemo4@ADDEMO.IT
        renew until 11/10/2017 15:18:48
```

Invoke ksu:

```
$ ksu kservice -n kservice@ADDEMO.IT -c FILE:./prova.cc
Authenticated kservice@ADDEMO.IT
Account kservice: authorization for kservice@ADDEMO.IT successful
Changing uid to kservice (50006)
groups: cannot find name for group ID 50024
```

It seems to work BUT it always ignores the service ticket and **performs again** from scratch **a TGS request** for host/authdemo4.
I have also checked (with Wireshark) differences between the responses of the *ksu* and *kvno* requests, ->I<- don't notice any difference (see attached image):
[image: Kerberos response for kvno and ksu, looks identical]
I have also tried using *ksu* more than once without purging the cache and the TGS request is performed again, each time.

**In brief: this attempt with end-server service ticket doesn't work (service ticket is always re-requested).**

**Questions**

They overlap a bit :-)

- is there a way to populate a Kerberos cache file with a service
  ticket that is compatible with *ksu*?
- Are there alternatives to *kvno* command in order to
  perform service ticket requests to TGS?
- Am I doing something wrong?
  Any tip?
- Do you think this is a ksu bug? :-)

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answers**

> Is there a way to populate a Kerberos cache file with a service ticket
>   that is compatible with ksu?

**NO**, since version 1.13 ksu doesn't take advantage of cached service tickets

> Are there alternatives to kvno command in order to perform service
>   ticket requests to TGS?

My searches **has not lead to alternatives** but the previous answer make this far less important to me

> Am I doing something wrong? Any tip?

**NO**, it seems I have worked right, the problem is the changed (not documented) ksu behaviour

> Do you think this is a ksu bug? :-)

**ABOUT YES**, it is a ksu bug or a documentation bug, developers changed the behaviour but forgot to sync with documentation

I filed a bug report and got feedback (Thanks to ksu maintainer Greg Hudson for the prompt support).
They state that a previous bugfix changed the ksu behaviour from version 1.13 and they have not noticed/not updated the documentation.

The submitted bug report:
http://krbdev.mit.edu/rt/Ticket/Display.html?id=8619

**The current ksu behaviour does not adhere to the documentation (about service ticket in cache).**

**With ksu version >= 1.13** the **end-server service ticket is not read/validated from cache file** BUT **only the cached TGT is validated**. When the ksu is invoked a service ticket request to TGS is performed  in order to validate the cached TGT.

<s>At the moment, they are still thinking about what to do. I reccomended to restore the documented behaviour, I'll update this question in the future with their final decision.</s>

**UPDATE**: They replied at the bug-request and decided to restore the documented behaviour, but `ksu` is not high priority in the Krb5 Project and they cannot guarantee a timetable for the work.